# AngularJS, redirect user with POST information from $scope to a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post, angularjs-scope

Using AngularJS (1.3.15), is there a way to redirect a user to a PHP page with form POST data? And if so, can you convert JSON (from $scope.formData) to be sent as POST?

$http has a method for this, though it appears to be done asynchronously. On success, you can redirect, though when you hit the page, the POST variable will be empty. Thoughts? Thanks!